# Optimization over linear combinition of min functions

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, linear-programming

Assume we are given these six variables: $x_{12},x_{21},x_{13},x_{31},x_{23},x_{32}$. Then if,

$A_{ij} = min\{x_{ij},x_{ji} \}, B_{ik} = min\{x_{ik} - A_{ij}, x_{ki} \}, C_{jk} = min\{x_{jk} - A_{ij},x_{kj} - B_{ik} \}$. We want to choose $i,j,k \in \{1,2,3\}$ to maximize $A_{ij} + B_{ik} + C_{jk}$.

Given the numerical value of $x_{12},x_{21},x_{13},x_{31},x_{23},x_{32}$, we can check all 6 possible assignments of $(i,j,k)$ (which are (1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)) to see which one maximizes $A + B + C$. But, I want to know what we can say if $x_{12},x_{21},x_{13},x_{31},x_{23},x_{32}$ are parameters. My guess is that we should minimize $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ik}$ because $A_{ij}$ appears in $B_{ik}$ and $C_{jk}$ with negative sign and $B_{ik}$ appears in $C_{jk}$ with negative sign. Any idea/suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by $\min ( x_{ij}, x_{ji} )$? $\min$ over which indices?

Comment: @copper.hat I mean minimum of $x_{ij}$ and $x_{ji}$.

Comment: I understand the symbols, but not what set of indices you mean. Did you mean $\min_{i,j} x_{ij}$?

Comment: @copper.hat we don't want to minimize $A$ directly, we want to maximize $A+B+C$, but it involves $A$ which is equal to the minimum value of $x_{ij}$ and $x_{ji}$.

Comment: Do you mean each pair of indices has its own $A$,  $A_{ij} = A_{ji} = \min \{x_{ij}.x_{ji}\}$?

Comment: @EricTowers yes, exactly. I edited the question.

Comment: Unfortunate to call the variable $A_{ij}$. Since you use subscript on $x$ to indicate indexing, one is fooled to believe that $A_{ij}$ means an element in a matrix, which it isn't.  Simply call it $A$ (which is a function of $i$ and $j$ and $x$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation here is that you want to optimize over indexing in variables. This requires, as far as I can see, mixed-integer programming, and some pretty nasty constructs. Essentially, you have to introduce logic models of the type "if i=1 and j=1 then xij=x(1,1)". Hence, you introduce 3 binaries for $i$, three binaries for $j$ and three binaries for $k$, and then start combining the cases, doing the implications using big-M models for instance.

Here is a test implementation in the MATLAB modelling language YALMIP (disclaimer, developed by me). The MILP that arises is solved in 0s using any efficient MILP solver, such as Gurobi, Mosek, CPLEX, ...

```
% Let x be a variable (we'll fix later for special case)
n = 3;
x = sdpvar(n,n,'full');

% Let YALMIP do the variable index modelling, i.e.., MILP models
% for indexing and min will be setup automatically behind the scene
intvar i j k
Aij = min(x(i,j),x(j,i));
Bik = min(x(i,k) - Aij,x(k,i));
Cjk = min(x(j,k) - Aij,x(k,j)-Bik);

% Solve special case x actually is constant with this value
X = randn(n);
Model = [1 <= [i j k] <= n, alldifferent([i j k]), X==x];
optimize(Model,-(Aij+Bik+Cjk))
value([i j k])

% Some other case where x is unknown but constrained
Model = [1 <= [i j k] <= n, alldifferent([i j k]), magic(3)>=x>=0];
optimize(Model,-(Aij+Bik+Cjk))
value([i j k])
value(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with linear programming, as the problem is equivalent to
$$
\mbox{Maximize }\quad Z= a+b+c
$$
subject to
\begin{align}
a&\le x_{ij}\quad & \forall i,j\\
a&\le x_{ji}\quad & \forall i,j\\
b &\le x_{ik}-a\quad & \forall i,k\\
b &\le x_{ki}\quad & \forall i,k\\
c &\le x_{jk}-a\quad & \forall k,j\\
c &\le x_{kj}-b\quad & \forall k,j
\end{align}

Comment: No, this is not the model asked for. Note that $A$ is a matrix of values, and the main complication in the model lies in the combinatoric selection from $x$  in the objective, not in the modelling of min. For instance, in your model, $a$ will correspond to the minimum of all values in $x$, whereas the model calls for the minimum of just two elements.

Comment: Scratch the sentence that $A$ is a matrix. $A_{ij}$ is a scalar.